# Improving a 'remote_function' using "advanced" AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to improve an AJAX request in a view file using the `remote_function` method. The following code will display the text `Fire AJAX` when the mouse pointer is over the `<div id="test_id_div">...</div>` and will call an action controller method on clicking on the `Fire AJAX`.

In the view file I have:

```
<div id="test_id_div">
  <span id="test_id_span" %> style="display: none">
    <%= link_to_function 'Fire AJAX', remote_function(:url => {:action => :action_method_name, :controller => 'controller_name'}) %>
  </span>

  <%=
    update_page_tag do |page|
      page.event.observe("test_id_div", 'mouseover') do |element|
        element[("test_id_span").to_sym].show
      end
      page.event.observe("test_id_div", 'mouseout') do |element|
        element[("test_id_span").to_sym].hide
      end
    end
  %>
</div>
```

The above code works, however I would like to improve that in some "better" way (example: writing less code, ...). **How could I do that?**

---

*P.S.*: In my case the `Fire AJAX` will call an action controller method that update a record in the database, so I would like to know what I should\must know about security matter too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to the `mouseover/out` effect, this could be achieved with a dash of CSS (not supported by IE6):

**ERB:**

```
<div id="test_id_div">
  <span id="test_id_span" %>>
    <%= link_to_function 'Fire AJAX', remote_function(:url => {:action => :action_method_name, :controller => 'controller_name'}) %>
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test_id_div span { display: none; }
#test_id_div:hover span { display: block; }
```

I'm neither using Prototype nor the related helpers, but I'm fairly sure that you should be able to use `link_to… :remote => true` in this case as well, since you don't seem to be calling a local JS function:

```
<%= link_to 'Fire AJAX', :action => :action_method_name, :controller => 'controller_name', :remote => true %>
```

And to simplify things even further: if you want to simply hide/show the link, why not get rid of one container?

```
<div id="test_id_div">
  <%= link_to 'Fire AJAX', :action => :action_method_name, :controller => 'controller_name', :remote => true %>
</div>

#test_id_div a { display: none; }
#test_id_div:hover a { display: block; }
```

I hope I've not misunderstood you somewhere, but this should do the trick.